# Проблема с нанесением урона персонажу

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть персонаж и монстр. Когда персонаж касается монстра, у персонажа должно отниматься здоровье. Скрипт с HealthBar`ом отлично работает и если в Update написать чтобы отнимались жизни всё работает. Но скрипт, который "лежит" на монстре не работает.

Скрип HeathBar`а:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HealsBar : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float maxHeals;
    public Texture HealsTexture;
    public float dmg;

    private float BarWidth;
    private float realHeals;
    private float TextureWidth;


    void Start()
    {
        BarWidth = Screen.width / 4;
        realHeals = maxHeals;
        TextureWidth = BarWidth;
    }




    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 10, BarWidth, 40), realHeals + " for " + maxHeals);

        if (HealsTexture != null && TextureWidth > 0)
        {
            GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(10, 30, TextureWidth, 15), HealsTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleAndCrop, true, 10.0f);
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        calculatedHeals();
    }


    public void calculatedHeals()
    {
        if (realHeals - dmg > 0)
        {
            realHeals = realHeals - dmg;
            TextureWidth = BarWidth * (realHeals / maxHeals);
        }
        else
        {
            realHeals = 0.0f;
            TextureWidth = 0.1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Скрипт монстра:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MonsterAtack : MonoBehaviour {

    float enemyDamage = 7.0f;
    public Transform target;
    GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        target = go.transform;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            HealsBar hb = target.GetComponent<HealsBar>();
            hb.calculatedHeals(enemyDamage);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Ошибки]

Буду благодарен!
P.S. Unity ругаеться на: 1. No overload for method `calculatedHeals' takes`1' arguments. 2.The name `target' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Скрипт монстра и healthbar одно и тоже?

Comment: 1. No overload for method calculatedHeals' takes1' arguments. Компилятор ругается на то, что вы пытаетесь вызвать  calculatedHeals с передачей ему параметра, а такой перегрузки не существует. 2The name `target' does not exist in the current context Вы обращаетесь к переменой target, которая не определена в текущей области видимости. Код для монстра вывестите

Comment: @AndreiS. Не подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ нет это разные вещи, скрипт монстра должен отнимать здоровье у персонажа при соприкосновении, а HeathBar содержит здоровье персонажа и команду которая отнимает здоровье, в скрипте для монстра просто надо сделать ссылку на эту команду с уроном и указать сам урон.

Comment: Так я за метил то что случайно написала одно и тоже, прошу извенений

Comment: что такое target в HealsBar hb = target.GetComponent<HealsBar>; ? Оно у вас берется из ниоткуда. Это ошибка №2

Comment: @AndreiS. сам понял, но не пойму теперь как исправить чтобы нормально заработало

Comment: Вы должны понять что такое target и как его получить, из приведенного я этого сделать не могу

Comment: @AndreiS. дописал пару строк в скрипте, но что то всё равно не работает

Comment: @max5937 новый код с теми же дырами и десятком новых. Вы хоть немного изучите  c#, хотя бы базовый синтаксис. Вы конечно извините, но вы вообще не понимаете что вы делаете.

Answer (score 1):

Измените ваш класс MonsterAtack

```
public class MonsterAtack : MonoBehaviour {

  float enemyDamage = 7;
  HealsBar hb;
  public MonsterAtack()
  {
     hb = GetComponent<HealsBar>();
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
  {
      if (collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
      {
        hb.dmg = enemyDamage;
        hb.calculatedHeals();
      } 
  }
}
```

Comment: А, что с этим делать? `HealsBar hb = target.GetComponent<HealsBar>;`
Что вместо target написать?

Comment: Появилась вот такая ошибка: A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent<HealsBar>()'

Comment: Для решения этой проблемы используйте конструктор типа